# dwm. How to switch between last two windows?

Tags: dwm

I find no way to switch between last two focused windows. How can I do that? There is <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but for tags only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggling between windows in a tag is done through changing the focus between next and previous:

> Mod1-j Focus next window.
>
> Mod1-k Focus previous window.

Comment: Oh...my) Thank you. But that's certainly not what I'm looking for. I think if the person use dwm he can miss these combinations in the first place:)

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov That's *not* what you are looking for? How so?

Comment: \*can't - above, btw. Answering you question: because you suggest switching b/w next/previous. What I ask how to switch b/w *last focused* windows. Hence if there are 3 windows mod-k/j will just cycle all the three. I need to switch only two among them.

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov Try it: it cycles between the last two if you toggle j/k (that's what next and previous means)...

Comment: Yep, the trick is when there are only 3 windows you indeed able to switch between last two (since all wins are reachable on cycling). But what you say if there are 4 windows? [1], 2, [3], 4 where [] means last focused. How would you cycle b/w 1 & 3?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov You can't; because you could never have jumped between 1 & 3 in the first place (with just the keyboard). For that level of functionality, you would want a WM more like Xmonad.

Comment: Yea, you right if we speak in terms of keyboard. But sometimes you can jump it just using mouse (the functionality of which dwm provides). So anyway thank you for your responses. Probably the last suggestion will "dig into the code, hack it, patch it!" :)

Answer (score 0):

there's a patch called swapfocus. it allows you to switch focus with one single shortcut.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).